# Cplex-Reading Data From Excel File

Tags: excel, cplex, opl

I have a problem where i can't load my data from EXCEL file. Here is my code,

```
in mod file

    int i = ...;
    range values = 1..i;
    int storage[values] = ...;

in dat file
    SheetConnection store("DataSet-5.xlsx");

storage from SheetRead(store,"'Sheet1'!B2:B201"); ##Sheet1 is the sheet name where the data is located.
    i = 201;
```

File is in the same location as my project. But it gives Internal Error.

Comment: Just to be sure : do you run on Windows ? And do you have excel installed ? If yes to both , can you try the oil excel example in  CPLEX_Studio129\opl\examples\opl\oil ?

Comment: In case all that Alex suggested suceeds, can you please add the exact error message you get?